# Mongoose does not produce a result but mongo shell does

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, robo3t

I have schema for products and it has a field storeZones object in it defined as

```
...
storeZones: {
  type: {
    masterZone: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, model: 'Zone', index: 1 },
    zone: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, model: 'Zone', index: 1 },
    subZone: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, model: 'Zone', index: 1 },
    },
    default: {
      masterZone: null,
      zone: null,
      subZone: null,
    },
  },
...
```

I am counting for products in a specific `masterZone`. So my query is

```
const condition = { 'storeZones.masterZone': masterZone };

console.log(condition); // { 'storeZones.masterZone': '60533e6a745d465ab6cb3fc9' }

const total = await Product.count(condition);
```

This returns 0 results.
But when i paste the exact query in mongo shell; Robo3t to be exact.

```
db.products.find({'storeZones.masterZone': ObjectId('60533e6a745d465ab6cb3fc9') } )
```

It produces the desired output. Can someone please provide some assistance?

Comment: Fixed it by converting  `masterZone` from `string` to an `ObjectId` in the mongoose query manually. It is odd that i had to do it manually because mongoose does that on its own as i have defined masterZone to be an `ObjectId`.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it by converting the `masterZone` from request to an `ObjectId`. Idk why i needed to do this, but that fixed it! so...

```
  const m = mongoose.Types.ObjectId(masterZone);
  const condition = { 'storeZones.masterZone': m };
  console.log(condition); // { 'storeZones.masterZone': '60533e6a745d465ab6cb3fc9'}
  const total = await Product.count(condition);
```